# I have coded for class balancing loss

Tags: loss

## Other class balancing loss

```
            class_weights = 1.0/np.mean(mdlParams['labels_array'][mdlParams['trainInd'],:],axis=0)
            print("Current class weights",class_weights) 
            class_weights = class_weights*mdlParams['extra_fac']
            print("Current class weights with extra",class_weights) 
        elif mdlParams['balance_classes'] == 9:
```

error says:
class_weights_ = 1.0/np.mean(mdlParams['labels_array'][indices_ham,:8],axis=0)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Answer (score 0):

mdlParams is a 1 dimension array so calling

```
mdlParams['labels_array'][mdlParams['trainInd']
```

will yield you an error.

To explain a bit better, mdlParams is lets say an array of size [10]

but you are trying to read mdlParams[10][1] while there is no second dimension to accept the 1